# How do I splice a 2D array in Google Apps Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to splice a 2D array in Google Apps Script. I have the following code, but it only works with a 1D array:

```
function trimArray() {
  var myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6,', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
  myArray.splice(3, myArray.length);
  console.log(myArray);
}
```

How do I modify the code above to work with this array?

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6,', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

The output should be the same as the function above, but still maintain a 2D array:

```
[['1', '2', '3']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
function test() {
  try {
    let a = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6,', '7', '8', '9', '10']];
    a[0] = a[0].slice(0,3);
    console.log(a)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err);
  }
}

2:59:19 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:59:20 PM  Info    [ [ '1', '2', '3' ] ]
2:59:20 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function splicearray() {
  let arr = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9]];
  arr.splice(1,0,[4,5,6]);
  Logger.log(arr);
}

Execution log
2:11:54 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:11:54 PM  Info    [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
2:11:55 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

I don't understand your example if I wanted to be left with a 2 d array as you show I would do it this way:

```
function trimArray() {
  let arr = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6,', '7', '8', '9', '10']];
  arr.splice(0,1, [1,2,3]);
  Logger.log(arr);
}

Execution log
2:23:26 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:23:26 PM  Info    [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
2:23:27 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```